# Ругается на (this, MainActivity1_1.class); в .setPositiveButton

Tags: java, android

```
 public  void  Buy_nomer(View view){

        Vibro = (Vibrator)this.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        Vibro.vibrate(50);


        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Alert", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean AlertState = prefs.getBoolean("Alert", Alert);


        if (AlertState == false) {

            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle(R.string.review)


                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {


                Alert = false;
                SharedPreferences.Editor ed = getSharedPreferences("Alert", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                ed.putBoolean("Alert", Alert);
                ed.commit();

                //выход
            }
        })


                    .setNeutralButton(R.string.read_the_rules, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                Alert = false;
                SharedPreferences.Editor ed = getSharedPreferences("Alert", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                ed.putBoolean("Alert", Alert);
                ed.commit();

                Policy(null);

            }
        })

                .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        //

                        Alert = true;
                        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = getSharedPreferences("Alert", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                        ed.putBoolean("Alert", Alert);
                        ed.commit();

                        // finish();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity1_1.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                })

                .create().show();

    }
        else
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity1_1.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так работает

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity1_1.class);
```